# C#: How to download and upload file from Sharepoint Teamsite Site

Tags: c#, wpf, sharepoint, webdav

I have a Sharepoint Teamsite where I have a file stored in a folder, I want to download it, and upload a new file back to another folder on the same site.

To be precise, my site url is `https://sharepoint.wsx.sg/sites/op/SitePages/Home.aspx`, I would like to download the file `conf.json` which is located at `/files/config/conf.json` , then my C# WPF program will do it's thing, and upload a new file to `/files/result/result.json` .

How would I be able to achieve this using C# code? I read about a WebDav protocol, but couldn't really figure out how to use it, or if I need to download any packages.

Wondering if anyone could offer an alternative method of doing so, or point me to some helpful links, would greatly appreciate it!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you just want to "copy" an item from a list to another. This can be achieved very easily using Server Side Object Model (SSOM).

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("<Site URL>"))
{
    SPList sourceList = site.RootWeb.Lists["SourceListName"];
    sourceList.GetItemById(0).File.CopyTo("DestinationListUrl");
}
```

Of course maybe you will get your SPListItem in another manner and you have to ensure that the SourceList exists, site url is correct etc.

The more important question is, when do you want to trigger this copy? Does this have to happen everytime a new item is added to this source list? Then you would need an EventReceiver. If you want to do this copy of items every minute/hour/day you'll need to implement a timer job.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply, I noticed from your reply that I wasn't clear enough in my question. Edited the question to add more details.